# Get text from notification login message

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a Angular application which I would like to test using Selenium Web Driver with Java.
After successful or unsuccessful user login notification message is displayed into the web page:

```
<div class="overlay-container">
   <div id="toast-container" class="toast-top-right toast-container">
      <div toast-component="" class="toast-error ngx-toastr ng-trigger ng-trigger-flyInOut" style="opacity: 1;">
         <!----><button aria-label="Close" class="toast-close-button ng-tns-c11-11 ng-star-inserted" style=""><span class="ng-tns-c11-11" aria-hidden="true">×</span></button><!----><!----><!---->
         <div aria-live="polite" role="alertdialog" class="toast-message ng-star-inserted" aria-label="Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password." style=""> Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password. </div>
         <!---->
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

I would like to intercept the text of the message. I tried this:

// //*[@id="toast-container"]

```
// //*[@id="toast-container"]/div/div

// Click Login button to submit login form
WebDriverWait failedLoginWebDriverWait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 7000);

WebElement failedLoginWebElement = failedLoginWebDriverWait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@id='toast-container']")));
boolean displayed = failedLoginWebElement.isDisplayed();
WebElement element = failedLoginWebElement.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='toast-container']/div/div"));
String text = element.getText();

System.out.println("displayed label: " + displayed);
System.out.println("text: " + text);
```

I get false and NPE for the second `findElement`.

Do you know how I can solve this issue?

Comment: Can you share your url?

Comment: It's a internal system.

Answer (score 0):

`isDisplayed()` is returning false. This might be because you're looking (waiting) for the presence of the element in the DOM. This doesn't mean it `isDisplayed()`. It's a bit complicated, there is a good answer [here](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/a/6556/34209) but in summation, it's size needs to be non-zero and some atrributes must be set for it to be considered Displayed. Likely the toast is IN the DOM, but not yet fully rendered to be considered displayed.

The second issue with the NPE might be the fact you're taking the toast element and doing a findElement on it which means the xpath is going to be executed relative to the toast element. Which means the xpath is actually executing as:

```
//*[@id='toast-container']/.//*[@id='toast-container']/div/div
```

which is not what you truly want. You likely want to just do:

```
WebElement element = failedLoginWebElement.findElement(By.xpath("/div/div"));
```